# Laravel Eloquent for loop query to single prepared query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Need some help converting the following Laravel Eloquent for loop query into a single MySQL query that hits the database a single time. Basically this will hit the database n number of times based on how many items are in $cardQueryList.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($cardQueryList); $i++) {
        $userCard = Collection::firstOrNew( ['username' => $cardQueryList[$i]['username'], 'card_uid' => $cardQueryList[$i]['card_uid']] );
        $userCard->have_quantity = $cardQueryList[$i]['have_quantity'];
        $userCard->save();
}
```

This is what I currently have:

```
DB::raw('REPLACE INTO users_collection (username, card_uid, have_quantity) values('.$cardQueryList[$i]["username"].', '.$cardQueryList[$i]["card_uid"].', '.$cardQueryList[$i]["have_quantity"].')');
```

The problem is I'm using 'username' and 'card_uid' together as a unique key to find the corresponding row to update. Another issue is this requires me to specify all values for all fields otherwise fields will get lost or replaced with default values.

How can I have a raw MySQL query hit the database once instead of n times like in the Laravel Eloquent code? Or is there a way to hit the database once with just Eloquent (this would be the best but I don't think there's a way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

```
$last = count($cardQueryList)-1;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO users_collection (username, card_uid, have_quantity) VALUES ';
for($i=0; $i<$last; $i++) {
   $sql .= '("'. $cardQueryList[$i]['username'] .'", "'. $cardQueryList[$i]['card_uid'] .'", '. $cardQueryList[$i]['have_quantity'] .'), ';
}
$sql .= '("'. $cardQueryList[$last]['username'] .'", "'. $cardQueryList[$last]['card_uid'] .'", '. $cardQueryList[$last]['have_quantity'] .') ';
$sql .= 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ';
for($i=0; $i<$last; $i++) {
    $sql .= 'have_quantity = '. $cardQueryList[$i]['have_quantity'] .', ';
}
$sql .= 'have_quantity = '. $cardQueryList[$last]['have_quantity'];

DB::statement($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit** based on your comments, you can do a mass update with `DB` using something like the following:

```
DB::table((new Collection)->getTable())->update([
    [
        'field' => 'value',
        'field2' => 'value 2',
    ],
    [
        'field' => 'value',
        'field2' => 'value 3',
    ],
])
->where('some_id', $id);
```

---

Is a raw SQL really what you're looking  for, or could you simply do something along these lines:

```
foreach ($cardQueryList as $cardQuery) {
    $userCard = Collection::where('username', $cardQuery['username'])
        ->where('card_uid', $cardQuery['card_uid'])
        ->firstOrNew();

    $userCard->have_quantity = $cardQuery['have_quantity'];
    $userCard->save();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the fundamental problem of for looping n amount of times based on how many items cardQueryList has.

Comment: Yes it does, `foreach` will iterate the number of items within the `$cardQueryList` array, giving `$cardQuery` as each item within.  It's identical to your for loop, but cleaner.  The difference here is how I use `where` as conditions to query for the record as you want and create it should it not exist.

Comment: No, it does not solve the question I'm asking. Every time this line happens, $userCard->save(); it hits the database. You're code is hitting the database the exact same number of times as mine. The question is how can I send a single query to the database ONE time and update (or insert) the database with all corresponding items in $cardQueryList.

Comment: Ah interesting, will that insert if the row doesn't exist?

Comment: Sadly not, you will have to go down the replace into route.  Though, I don't think  it's necessary.  Baring in mind replace into does not update but instead creates new records with the updated data. I would go for my latter route.  If you seriously care about performance then an ORM is the last thing you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look though.